# SNMP traffic captured by Wireshark, but source port and destination port is same

Tags: snmp

As my knowledge, in normal behavior, client will make random port to connect the SNMP service port, now the client use SNMP trap port (162) to communicate with server.

My questions:

1. As the client setting, I do not have configure any SNMP setting for the client, why WireShark able to capture SNMP traffic came from the client?
2. Why the client use SNMP trap port (162) to communicate with server, rather than using random port?

[image: Screenshot from Wireshark]

Comment: I do not understand your question #1. Could you clarify it?

Comment: 1) You can capture anything in Wireshark and then filter them by protocols. Depending how you used Wireshark to capture the packets, that can be perfectly normal. 2) "A random port" is an illusion. The client can use an arbitrary port as long as it likes, and port 162 if available can be such a port. The source code of the client might tell more on how it chooses a port, which you did not reveal in your question.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, for the question 1, the client device has not any SNMP services(server / trap) is running, and the wireshark capture is implemented after the client device just finished OS installation, so that I don't know why the client device will send out SNMP traffic to a unknown server 192.168.0.3

Answer (score 2):

SNMP is usually transmitted over UDP, so there is actually no "connection", and speaking technically the source port doesn't matter. You can just send out datagrams (e.g. traps) without binding to a port.

However, even when run over UDP, SNMP does involve some two-way communication. If you are expecting a response (which a client does if it's sending an SNMP Get or Set request), the only place the other end knows to send it is back where the request came from, i.e. the original IP/port combination. There's no information in a SNMP packet that provides any alternative "return address" information.

So, in order to get a response on a predictable port, you'll send the request datagram from a *bound* socket. Typically the client will run its own listening "server" on port 162, send requests from there, *and then it can receive responses there too*. Otherwise you wouldn't see the responses. This also allows us to set up simple firewall rules (though you can often get away without firewall rules for the return path, due to [*hole punching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking))*).

This is also true for the server, which emits traps and informs on a known, standard, predictable port not only so that you can configure your trap receiver and firewalls in a reliable way, but so that inform responses can be sent back to a known, standard, predictable port that you're listening on.

**tl;dr:** You can send your requests from an arbitrary port if you like, but it's not very useful.

---

* My SNMP implementation seemed buggy when the client/receiver only saw traps emitted during the ~15 minutes after it had last poked out some kind of request packet. Subsequent traps seemed to be completely missing. After much debugging on the server end, it turned out that we'd forgotten to open the correct port on the inbound firewall for the client, and were accidentally relying on hole punching, which has a time limit. :D

---

As for why Wireshark is seeing traffic from an unconfigured SNMP client, well, either your SNMP client actually *is* configured to send requests, or you're misinterpreting the results. Wireshark doesn't invent traffic. Without a more complete picture of your network setup, software setup, and those packets you're seeing, we could only speculate as to the exact cause of your confusion.